# Phonegap/Android pagechange handler firing twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a problem where the pagechange handler is firing twice within my app for some page transitions.
In deviceready handler:

```
$(document).bind("pagechange", onPageChange);
```

Then the hander:

```
var onPageChange = function (event, data) {
    var fromPageId = null;

    //Get the ID of the page we are transitioning to.
    var toPageId = data.toPage.attr("id");

    //Get the ID of the page we are coming from.
    if (data.options.fromPage) {
        fromPageId = data.options.fromPage.attr("id");
    }

    console.log("pagechange to " + toPageId + " from " + fromPageId);

    switch (toPageId){
        ...
    }
}
```

When the app transitions from one page to the next, I can see in LogCat that the onPageChange is firing twice:

```
01-26 18:49:50.490: I/Web Console(18244): pagechange to care-plan-view from care-plan-view:25
01-26 18:49:50.490: I/Web Console(18244): pagechange to care-plan-view from care-plans:25
```

This is the order they appear in the log, weird thing is that the care-plan-view is the destination page and the care-plans is the start page!

This is a sample link that will cause the page transition issue:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#care-plan-view?id=9e273f31-2672-47fd-9baa-6c35f093a800&amp;name=Sat"><h3>Sat</h3></a>
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the **`pagechange`** event occurs twice is due to the recursive call in **`changePage`** when toPage is not a jQuery enhanced DOM object.

This recursion is dangerous, as the developer is allowed to change the toPage within the event. If the developer consistently sets toPage to a string, within the **`pagechange`** event handler, regardless of whether or not it was an object an infinite recursive loop will result.

The **`pageload`** event passes the new page as the page property of the data object (This should be added to the documentation, it's not listed currently). The **`pageload`** event could therefore be used to access the loaded page.

In few words this is happening because you are sending additional parameters through **`pageChange`**.

To fix this problem choose an another page event, like:

```
event pagebeforecreate
event pagecreate
event pageinit
event pagebeforehide
event pagebeforeshow
event pageremove
event pagehide
event pageshow
```

More about this problem can be found in my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, just search for the chapter: **Prevent multiple event triggering**. Or you can find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.